# Reponse object not working, What is wrong here?

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit

I've setup a php app that listens for the alexa request and generates the response. The testing portal doesn't really give you a lot of feedback, just that it's not working.

What amazon is sending.

```
{
"session": {
    "sessionId": "SessionId.here",
    "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.here"
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.here"
    },
    "new": true
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "EdwRequestId.here",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "timestamp": "2017-02-22T21:33:26Z",
        "intent": {
          "name": "PlayTheStream",
          "slots": {}
        }
    },
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

My response is this.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Now streaming this stream"
    },
    "card": {
      "type": "Simple",
      "title": "Play Audio",
      "content": "Playing the requested stream."
    },
    "directives": {
      "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
      "playBehavior": "ENQUEUE",
      "audioItem": {
        "stream": {
          "token": "this-is-the-audio-token",
          "url": "http://functionalstream.com/playlist.m3u",
          "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "shouldEndSession": true
}
```

Response headers

```
cache-control →no-cache, private
content-type →application/json
date →Wed, 22 Feb 2017 21:33:10 GMT
server →nginx/1.11.2
status →200
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection →1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returned stream needs to be an https target with a proper certificate.  You have a http destination.

Comment: The audio stream needs to be secure too?

Comment: Yes. For a quick test find a suitable online file and use that URL.

Comment: I tried putting an mp3 on the server and playing it locally. Just replacing the url with the direct link to the url and that failed too. Could I be doing something wrong with my server? Its on a server with letsencrypt ssl.

Comment: If it is the same server that is serving up the response, it isn't the certificate.  If it isn't try embedding an audio resource in your code just to make sure it isn't the cert.  Amazon provides no useful diagnostic info.  The fetch is from the AWS servers (I think) not from the Echo/AVS device.

Comment: It's the same server sending the response. I'm not doing any validation on the request nor am i providing a real token. All I did was replace the url in the code snippet at the top with a link to a file in the pub directory on the same server and put an absolute link to it. https://server/file.mp3 I'm lost at this point lol

Comment: Looking at the examples, I see that directives is an array of objects.  See the example on https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference#directives